# I have problems making a function to handle a matrix using calloc

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing, calloc

I want to dynamicly construct a matrix in C from a text document using a function.
I ran into problems when making the matrix using calloc and probably when giving the values to the matrice elements, and I couldn't find anything. I can handle a vector.

**Code here:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void beolvas_ellista(int *, int *, int *, int *, int ***, char *);

int main()
{
    int ir, suly, csom, el, i, **ellista;

    //The following commented code works
    /*FILE * f;
    f=fopen("be.txt","r");

    fscanf(f,"%d",&ir);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&suly);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&csom);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&el);

    ellista=(int **)calloc(2,sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<el;++i)
    {
        ellista[i]=(int *)calloc(el,sizeof(int));
    }
    i=0;
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&ellista[0][i]);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&ellista[1][i]);
        ++i;
    }

    for(i=0;i<el;++i)
        printf("%d %d\n",ellista[0][i],ellista[1][i]);

    fclose(f);*/

    beolvas_ellista(&ir, &suly, &csom, &el, &ellista, "be.txt");

    for(i=0;i<el;++i)
        printf("%d %d\n",ellista[0][i],ellista[1][i]);

    return 0;
}

void beolvas_ellista(int *ir, int *suly, int *csom, int *el, int ***ellista, char *allomany)
{
    int i;
    FILE * f;
    f=fopen(allomany,"r");

    fscanf(f,"%d",ir);
    fscanf(f,"%d",suly);
    fscanf(f,"%d",csom);
    fscanf(f,"%d",el);

    *ellista=(int **)calloc(2,sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<*el;++i)
    {
        *ellista[i]=(int *)calloc(*el,sizeof(int));
    }

    i=0;
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d",ellista[0][i]);
        fscanf(f,"%d",ellista[1][i]);
        ++i;
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Here is the text file:

be.txt

```
0 0
7 8
1 2
1 3
2 3
3 4
4 5
4 6
5 7
6 7
```

Also here is the code that I used to gather information:

```
void beolvas(int*pn, int**pa, char*allomany)
{
int i;FILE*f;
f=fopen(allomany,"r");
fscanf(f,"%d",pn);
*pa=(int*)malloc((*pn)*sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i<*pn; i++)
fscanf(f,"%d",(*pa)+i);
fclose(f);
}
main()
{
int n, *a;
beolvas(&n, &a, "be.txt");
...
}
```

Comment: `int ***` is the sign of that you're doing something very, *very* wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3 if there is a better way of doing it can you give me an example please, i only know this type of transmitting 2D matrix as a poiter.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use a true 2D array (or at least a pointer to its first element): `int (*arr)[COLS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *arr);`, etc. Also, please format your code (use indentation, whitespace) and use English function and variable names so that the code is easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bullet-list the items wrong in your function.

- You're incorrectly using `feof()` as the break condition of your `while` loop. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for more information.
- You ignore the return result of [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and with that thereby have no assurance at all the parameter parsing succeeded or not. [See the documentation of `fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).
- Your code does not fit the model of the file content. The file, according to your code, should set `ir`, `suly`, `csom`, and `el` to values `0`, `0`, `7`, and `8` respectively. You then allocate space for exactly **two** pointers-to-int, saving the result in `ellista`, then proceed to index into `*ellista` up to `el` items, which is clearly *not* `2`. It is neither clear nor evident that you want a 2xN matrix or an Nx2 matrix when this is finished, and the code as-written does *neither* correctly.
- Stylistic, but helpful: You should be setting your out-parameters on *success* of your function, not on initial entrance or parse. Eg: Your `ellista` by-address parameter should be set as the *last* operation, not the first, based on the success of the function. Declare a local `int** local;` temp var, run your algorithm populating that, and upon *success* set the out-parameter.

All of that said, I *think* you want a 2xN matrix, and if so, the code below will do that. Note this does *not* check the results of the malloc and calloc calls, which i leave to you. This function will return zero (`0`) on success, non-zero on failure :

```
int beolvas_ellista(int *ir, int *suly, int *csom, int *el, int ***ellista, const char *allomany)
{
    FILE * f = fopen(allomany,"r");
    int ** local =  NULL;
    int i, res = -1;

    if (f == NULL)
        return res;

    if (fscanf(f,"%d",ir) == 1 &&
        fscanf(f, "%d",suly) == 1 &&
        fscanf(f,"%d",csom) == 1 &&
        fscanf(f,"%d",el) == 1)
    {
        // allocate two pointers, then in those two pointers, allocate
        //  space for *el integers.
        local = malloc(2 * sizeof(*local));
        local[0] = calloc(*el, sizeof(*(local[0])));
        local[1] = calloc(*el, sizeof(*(local[0])));

        for (i=0; i<*el; ++i)
        {
            if (fscanf(f, "%d", local[0]+i) != 1 ||
                fscanf(f, "%d", local[1]+i) != 1)
                break;
        }

        // only if i == *el did we finish the above
        if (i == *el)
        {
            *ellista = local;
            res = 0;
        }
        else
        {   // failed to read file content. free up memory
            // and return error state.
            free(local[0]);
            free(local[1]);
            free(local);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file does not fit the code. You say in your input file *el = 8. In your code you take this as row count, but actually only spending 2 rows to the matrix in your first calloc call...

P.S. Try this instead:

Edit: Wrong analyse by me. Your actual problem is a predecence one. You need to dereference your *** in the right way with brackets set, like so:

```
void beolvas_ellista(int *ir, int *suly, int *csom, int *el, int ***ellista, char *allomany)
{
    int i;
    FILE * f;
    f=fopen(allomany,"r");

    fscanf(f,"%d",ir);
    fscanf(f,"%d",suly);
    fscanf(f,"%d",csom);
    fscanf(f,"%d",el);


    *ellista=(int **)calloc(2,sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<*el;++i)
    {
        (*ellista)[i]=(int *)calloc(*el,sizeof(int));

    }



    i=0;

    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&((*ellista)[0][i]));
        fscanf(f,"%d",&((*ellista)[1][i]));
        ++i;
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: the matrice is 2*8, i tested the code and it works, i have some poiter issues inside the function at allocating the space or when giving the values and i can't figure that out

Comment: @Miklosflame "i tested the code and it works" No it doesn't. Your `feof` check in your while-loop is wrong. `feof` will not be established on the last line read; it will be established on the first read-attempt *after* that. And the read-attempts you're using, `fscanf()` are completely unchecked for validity. In other words, assuming the sizing is done correctly, you're overrunning your allocated matrix size and walking straight into the land of **undefined behavior**. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: Please have a look at my edit, especially for the location in calloc and fscanf calls how to set brackets when dereferencing "ellista". My first analyse was wrong, sorry for that.

Comment: @user2927610 i've corrected that mistake but still get errors, so it is now because of the file reading.

Comment: @WhozCraig in the main function i had no problems with the feof, but now i'm trying to fix it

Comment: @Miklosflame You did, you just didn't know it.

Comment: @WhozCraig is it only the while loop error beside the correction of user2927610 ?

Comment: @Miklosflame No, thats not the only issue. But I see you were looking for a 2xN matrix, so I'll delete the second implementation in my answer.